# PHP Array: Group by portion of a string

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have an array containing the strings below

```
'Proxima Nova Bold'
'Proxima Nova Italic'
'Proxima Nova Regular'
'Skolar Bold'
'Skolar Italic'
'Skolar Regular'
'Consolas'
```

i'd like to have an output like

```
'Proxima' 
'Skolar' 
'Consolas'
```

essentially grouping by the parent/master name...is it possible in PHP?

Comment: You could try splitting strings on spaces, grabbing the first element in the resulting array, and then placing that element in an array if the entry doesn't yet exist.

Comment: why are there so many tags? you're asking if it's possible to do something in php but have included both javascript and mysql tags, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode each string into words, return the first word, and then use `array_unique` to remove the duplicates.

```
array_unique(array_map(function($str) {
    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    return $words[0];
}, $array));
```

Comment: you should add $array = array_values($array);
print_r($array);

Comment: @Francesco I was just showing how to get the result. What he does with it is his responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

This should be the easiest way to do it:

```
//Create an empty array
$new_array = array();
foreach($array as $value) {
  //Explode the text into a new array, separated by space
  $first_part = explode(" ", $value);
  //Push the first word into the new array
  array_push($new_array, $first_part[0]);
}
//Now get only unique values
print_r(array_unique($new_array));
```